# Images not showing pug, express node.js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I've gone through what I should do for setting up images to show in my application:

http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/serving-static-files-in-nodejs

I have the current directory structure:

```
rootproject
-public
--images
---image.jpg
server.js
```

server.js:

```
// require all dependencies
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var path = require('path');

// set up the template engine
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

index.pug:

```
html
    head
        title= title
    body
        img(src='/static/images/image.jpg' , alt='some image') 
        h1= message
```

This does not work though and shows me in the console: GET http://localhost:3000/static/images/image.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your static routes are set up, you should refer to your images in /public, not /static.

```
img(src='/public/images/image.jpg' , alt='some image')
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, In my server.js file it has

> app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

instead of like in the above question

> app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

so, that image path starts with **/public** not working for me. instead, I used **images/image.jpg**. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The path `/static/images/image.jpg` does not exist in the public directory, you have to remove `/static` and it should work:

```
img(src='/images/image.jpg' , alt='some image')
```

Comment: In server js they used app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); instead of app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); so, it should start with /public.